# How to make button continue it's behaviour in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, uibutton

I am learning iOS app development.
I am building  the classic 'Snakes' game.
I have got direction buttons in the app that change the direction of the snake.

However when I press a direction button, the snake only moves by 1 block. To make the snake continue to move, I have to repeatedly press the button.

Is there a way to use the buttons properties so that the snake does not stop until any other directional button is pressed?

Comment: I know nothing about iOS development or Objective-C but I _can_ tell you no one will be able to answer your question without seeing your code.

Comment: Wish I could post my code, but its forbidden by our university; they consider it cheating, someone else will correct my code and I will hand that in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure your events in storyboard, use onTouchDown and onTouchUpInside/Outside events.

The idea is when user touched down on a button, you want to set the snake's state to moving. When user's finger leaves button, you set the snake to stop moving.

Then in a separate loop, you move the snake according to its state governed by user input.

Comment: Okay, but is it possible to make the snake continue to move in a single direction even if the user releases the button? The direction changes when the user presses a different directional button.

Comment: Then what you want is to declare a variable, call it direction, and when user taps appropriate button, change the direction. In a separate loop you move the snake according to the direction. You can use a recurring timer that fires every second or so and use that to move your snake